# $f_X(x) = e^{-x} x \geq 0,$ 0 otherwise. Calculate $P(|X-m| \leq k \sigma)$ and compare to Chebyshev's bound.

Tags: probability-theory

So first,

$$E(X) = \int_0^\infty xe^{-x} = 1 = m.$$ 
$$Var(X) = E(X^2) - 1^2 = -1 + \int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-x} = 1.$$

So does $\sigma = \sqrt{(Var(X))} = 1$ or do I need to calculate something else?

Chebychev says

$$P(|X-m| \geq k \sigma) = P(|X-m|^2 \geq k^2 \sigma^2) \leq \frac{Var(X)}{k^2 \sigma^2} = 1/k^2.$$

To calculate explicitly, we have

$$P(|X-m| \geq k \sigma) = P(-k + 1 \geq X \geq k + 1) = e(e^{-k} - e^k).$$

Is this what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Your $\sigma$ is right. The probability calculation is not quite right, since it does not take into account the fact that the density function is $0$ when $x\lt 0$.

There are two cases to consider, $0\lt k\le 1$ and $k\gt 1$. We look at the case $k\gt 1$. The mean $\mu$ is $1$, so $\Pr(|X-\mu|\gt k\sigma=\Pr(|X-1|\gt k)$. Since our density function is $0$ when $x\lt 0$, this is just the probability that $X\gt 1+k$. This probability is $\int_{1+k}^\infty e^{-x}\,dx$, which is  $e^{-(1+k)}$.

**Remark:** If $0\lt k\le 1$, there is an additional term $\int_0^{1-k}e^{-x}\,dx$. But for $k\le 1$, the Chebyshev bound is uninteresting, since it says that the probability is $\le 1$, which is trivially true.